# Filter array by last value Toleranz

Tags: python-3.x, filtering

i‘ m using Python 3.7.
I have an Array like this:

```
L1 = [1,2,3,-10,8,12,300,17]
```

Now i want to filter the values(the -10 and the 300 is not okay)

The values in the array may be different but always counting up or counting down.

Has Python 3 a integrated function for that?

The result should look like this:

```
  L1 = [1,2,3,8,12,17]
```

Thank you !

Edit from comments:

> I want to keep each element if it is only a certain distance (toleranz: 10 f.e.) distance away from the one before.

Comment: The background is that i want to Filter some tick values from a Motor.(canOpen). Some Ticks are out of Range.so i must check if the last value are okay ( last value +-10)

Comment: I have not coded anything yet. But i would code it like this: for Each item in array check if item is between lastitem and a toleranz value.i thought python numpy got a function like this. But now i know i must code it by myself. Thanks

Comment: Okay thanks i will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is [a `list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). You can use [built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html):

```
L1 = [1,2,3,-10,8,12,300,17]

min_val = min(L1)  # -10
max_val = max(L1)  # 300
p = list(filter(lambda x: min_val < x < max_val, L1))  # all x not -10 or 300

print(p) # [1, 2, 3, 8, 12, 17]
```

Doku:

- [min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)
- [max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)
- [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

---

If you want instead an incremental filter you go through your list of datapoints and decide if to keep or not:

```
delta = 10
result = []
last = L1[0] # first one as last value  .. check the remaining list L1[1:]
for elem in L1[1:]:
    if last-delta < elem < last+delta:
        result.append(last)
        last = elem    

if elem-delta < result[-1] < elem+delta :
    result.append(elem)

print(result) # [1, 2, 3, 8, 12, 17]
```

Comment: Thank you thats it.